# Ajuda com While em Java

Tags: java, while

estou começando em Java e fiquei com uma dúvida sobre como inserir um laço While no código abaixo.
É um código simples que estou fazendo para praticar, mas não estou conseguindo criar o While nele.
Gostaria que ao final do programa, ele perguntasse se deseja refazer, se digitarmos "sim" o programa reiniciasse sozinho, se digitar "não", ele encerra.
Abaixo meu código.
Desde já, obrigado e estou aberto a sugestões, como já disse... sou iniciante nesse mundo de Java e programação, quero muito aprender.

```
package exercicios_java;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Par {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String numero = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Por favor digite um número entre 1 e 10: ");
        int num = Integer.parseInt(numero);
        int par = num % 2;

        if (num < 1 || num > 10) {
            String saida = "Por favor, digite um número válido!";
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, saida);
        } else if (par == 1) {
            String num_impar = "Seu número é ímpar!";
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, num_impar);
        } else {
            String num_par = "Seu número é par!";
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, num_par);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

O loop While permite verificação condicional no início ou no fim do bloco de instruções que serão repetidas.

Exemplo de Loop com verificação no início:

```java
while(condição){

//bloco de códigos

}
```

Exemplo de Loop com verificação no final:

```java
do{

//bloco de códigos

} while(condição);
```

No caso que você propôs o ideal seria fazer a verificação ao final do bloco de instruções para evitar alterar o fluxo normal da aplicação (linha por linha), apesar do While com verificação no começo também funcionar para este caso e ser a utilização mais comum deste loop.

O seu código será algo parecido com isso:

```java
do{

//todo o código que você quer que repita

String verifica = JOptionPane..showInputDialog("Se desejar refazer digite sim: ");

} while(verifica.equals("sim"));
```

Comment: Me ajudou muito, eu estava esquecendo de tilizar o DO.
Mas agora consegui fazer, muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score -3):

De acordo com o seu enunciado o ideal e que você utilize um While ou Do-While.
Veja um exemplo;

```java
       String resp = "nao";
       while(resp.toLowerCase().equals("nao")){
        /* seu bloco aqui */
         resp = sc.nextLine(); //se aqui for um sim ele sai do while
       }
```

Answer (score -3):

No teu códigos está trasnformando em um número inteiro e isso não colabória para o código. O ideal é fazer uma mudança na estrutura do teu código em sí.

```java
import javax.swing.*;

public class Par {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String userInput;
        do {
            userInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Por favor digite um número entre 1 e 10: ");
        } while (checagem(userInput));
    }

    public static boolean checagem(String input) {
        int num = Integer.parseInt(input);
        int par = num % 2;
        if (num < 1 || num > 10) {
            String saida = "Por favor, digite um número válido!";
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, saida);
        } else if (par == 1) {
            String num_impar = "Seu número é ímpar!";
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, num_impar);
        } else {
            String num_par = "Seu número é par!";
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, num_par);
        }
        return (JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Deseja continuar? (Sim/Não) ")).equalsIgnoreCase("sim");
    }
}
```